# how to keep toolkit:listPicker selectedItem at a new page load WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, indexing, selecteditem, listpicker

I am using toolkit:listPicker for selection of vehicle from a list Collection, but when I go to another page and get back to the one with the listPicker tool, the selected index is changed to '0' (it is '-1' by default when the list is empty).
Please see my methods below:

```
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                ReadAllVehicleList dbVehicles = new ReadAllVehicleList();
                DB_VehicleList = dbVehicles.GetAllVehicles();
                pickVehicle.ItemsSource = DB_VehicleList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
    }
```

This one is calling following:

```
    public class ReadAllVehicleList
{
    DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
    public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> GetAllVehicles()
    {
        return Db_Helper.ReadVehicle();
    }
}

    //This class for perform all database CRUID operations
    public class DatabaseHelperClass
{
        SQLiteConnection dbConn;

        public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> ReadVehicle(){
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            List<Vehicle> myCollection = dbConn.Table<Vehicle>().ToList<Vehicle>();
            ObservableCollection<Vehicle> VehicleList = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>(myCollection);
            return VehicleList;
        }
}
```

And one selectionChanged event to get the selected vehicle and display all refuelings for it in a listBox tool:

```
        private void pickVehicle_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            if (pickVehicle.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
            VehiclesPage.selectedVehicle = pickVehicle.SelectedItem as Vehicle;//selectedVehicle присвоява избраното превозно средство.
            ReadAllRefuelingList dbRefuelings = new ReadAllRefuelingList();
            DB_RefuelingList = dbRefuelings.GetAllRefuelings();//Извличане на всички записи за зареждане на гориво от базата данни
            listBoxobj.ItemsSource = DB_RefuelingList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();//Показване на записите в обратен ред (descending) - най-новото ID се показва най-отгоре
            }
    }
```

XAML:

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="pickVehicle"     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Width="480" SelectionChanged="pickVehicle_SelectionChanged" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="Orange" Foreground="White">
        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
                                <Run Text="{Binding Make}"/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Model}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Here is an example of the problem. I have 2 vehicles in the Database/listPicker. Index'0' = BMW E46 and Index'1' = Opel Astra. I have selected Opel Astra (Index'1'), but when i go to another page and then back to this one, the index is goind back to '0'.

[Image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Znip.jpg)

Comment: Can anyone help with this? It is very urgent for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` of the `ListPicker` is set inside the Loaded event of the page.

```
   private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {       
             ReadAllVehicleList dbVehicles = new ReadAllVehicleList();
             DB_VehicleList = dbVehicles.GetAllVehicles();           
             pickVehicle.ItemsSource = DB_VehicleList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
        }
```

The Loaded event will be fired again when you come back to this page and hence the `ItemsSource` will be reset, changing the selected item.

Based on your requirement you can either shift the code to set `ItemSource` to some other place or may be store the `SelectedIndex` of the `ListPicker` and reassign while coming back.